# Xcode UI Testing - Drag and Drop

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, xcode7-beta5, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to create XCTestCase to test reordering in my outline view (in OS X app). When I use UI Test Recording feature, Xcode prints this:

```
window.outlines.staticTexts["<cell which I want to move>"].click()
```

I tried dragging the cell both inside or outside outline view, Xcode generates the same useless code.

Does anyone know how to test drag & drop correctly in Xcode 7?

Comment: Have you tried `public func pressForDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, thenDragToElement otherElement: XCUIElement)`

Comment: @NickMcConnell there's no such method. I'm afraid it's available on iOS only.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is new, but in Xcode 7.2, if you look at the header for `XCUIElement`, there's a `clickForDuration(thenDragToElement:)` function for OS X. Seems to work for me with `NSOutlineView`.

This is from the header...

```
/*!
 * Clicks and holds for a specified duration (generally long enough to start a drag operation) then drags
 * to the other element.
 */
public func clickForDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, thenDragToElement otherElement: XCUIElement)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Haven't seen this function before, perhaps it was added in Xcode 7.2

Comment: Also works with Xcode 8/ Swift 3, but the function is: `func press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherElement: XCUIElement)`. With Swift 2.3 it is `func pressForDuration(duration: TimeInterval, thenDragToElement otherElement: XCUIElement)`

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 9.4.1
Swift:

```
func press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherElement: XCUIElement)
```

Example:

```
let ele: XCUIElement = XCUIApplication()!.otherElements.matching(identifier: "element_identifier").element(boundBy: 0)
ele.press(forDuration: <timeIntervalInSec>, thenDragTo: <destination_XCUIElement>)
```

Refer: [API Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618670-press)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. No solution. Looks like accessibility does not support d-n-d, and Apple docs say: [Provide alternatives for drag-and-drop operations.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXDeveloping.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to try checking the accessibility features of the code being tested. UI Testing needs to have accessibility information to be able to understand what is happening in the UI. See the [Apple WWDC15 UI Testing video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/) at about 39:30 into the video for an example of how to fix issues where UI recording can't properly generate code.